# QPainter. Draw line

Tags: qt, qpainter

I am trying to draw line.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    QPainter painter(&w);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 12, Qt::DashDotLine, Qt::RoundCap));
    painter.drawLine(0, 0, 200, 200);

    return a.exec();
}
```

But there is nothing painting on the window. What is wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can not paint outside of the `paintEvent()` function, at least on Windows and Mac OS. However you can override your `MainWindow` class' `paintEvent()` function to draw the line there. For example:

```
class Widget : public QWidget
{
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
    {
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 12, Qt::DashDotLine, Qt::RoundCap));
        painter.drawLine(0, 0, 200, 200);
    }
};
```

And the usage:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Widget w;
    w.show();
    [..]
```

Answer (score 16):

You can't paint on a widget outside of a paint event. But you can paint at any time on a non-widget, such as on a `QImage`, `QPixmap` or a `QPicture`:

[image: screenshot]

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);

   QPicture pi;
   QPainter p(&pi);   
   p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
   p.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 12, Qt::DashDotLine, Qt::RoundCap));
   p.drawLine(0, 0, 200, 200);
   p.end(); // Don't forget this line!

   QLabel l;
   l.setPicture(pi);
   l.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Widgets can be painted on only in their respective paint event. You can draw on a pixmap in any function, but you need to show the result in the widget paint event.

From the doc:

> Warning: When the paintdevice is a widget, QPainter can only be used
>   inside a paintEvent() function or in a function called by
>   paintEvent(); that is unless the Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent widget
>   attribute is set.